# Finding a referenced table in multiple views using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a huge database with 50+ Views, Tables and Stored Procedures. I want to run a search to find I specific piece of text, i.e a table name, to see if it is being referenced anywhere.

I originally tried a C# route but I am suspecting this will be easier in SQL. The logic I am thinking about is possibly creating a query that loops through all Tables, Views and Stored Procedures and returns the data if it is available.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Red Gate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/?&gclid=Cj0KEQjw4827BRDJvpbVuKvx-rIBEiQA2_CzsLcNl9GEdBZm9PN7w5F6pN7u4304dEv9Z_CNdFCQaosaAvji8P8HAQ) have a great, free, addin for SSMS that can do this.  It is called [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/).

Comment: Oh wow great! See that's the thing with being a new developer: it has probably already been done. Thanks alot! I have some good reading material now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below query, instead of the **matchingstring** replace your tablename, it will returns list of objects related to the search string

```
SELECT DISTINCT SO.[name]
FROM sysobjects SO 
JOIN syscomments SC ON SC.Id = SO.Id 
WHERE SC.[text] LIKE '%matchingstring%'
```

Comment: Tried and Tested, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT object_name(id) FROM sys.syscomments WHERE text LIKE'%yourtablename%'
```